# Does Kendo grid support scaffolding / auto generate columns

Tags: grid, kendo-ui

I am using MVC4 and I want to be able to bind my grid to a model and have it generate the columns at run time. I have done this before with the .asp version of the control and I am new to the Kendo UI version. I read that I should not use the MVC versions from telerik since they are being obsoleted. I have looked for an example of how to do this without luck. (both on their site and on the google)

I do not have to use the Kendo grid control so if there is something better out there that works with MVC I would love to know that as well. There are some advanced features I will want to make use of such as the detail template eventually.

Thanks in advance for any help,
 Scott

Comment: Where is your data coming from?

Comment: Data is coming from an Entity Framework model. I however do not want to have it bound to any particular model, but to expose all columns at run time. Again I could do this with the .asp version of the grid.

Answer (score 1):

the column factory object provides this.  for example this:

```
.Columns(col => {
  col.Bound(c => c.columnname1);
  col.Bound(c => c.columnname2);
  col.Bound(c => c.columnname3);
  col.Bound(c => c.columnname4);
})
```

would become this:

```
.Columns(col => {
   col.AutoGenerate(true);
})
```